# Looking for a reference for the laplacian operator 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Can anyone give me a reference which explain the derivation of the partial differential operator expression for the laplacian on the euclidean n-dimensional space and on $S^n$ ?

One generally writes the laplacian on the n-dim euclidean space as a sum of a operator on the radial coordinate and $\frac{1}{r^2}$ times the laplacian on $S^n$.

And very often the laplacian on $S^n$ is written through a recursion relation.

I am looking for a reference which shows me the derivations of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laplacian can be defined on any Riemannian manifold as div grad.  Here grad f for f a smooth function is the vector field dual to the 1-form df via the bilinear form of the metric.  Div of a vector field X corresponds to taking the covariant derivative $\nabla X$, which is a (1,1) tensor, and taking the trace of that.  In local coordinates one can give a formula using the symbols for the metric, which should yield what you are looking for.

Another way to define div is to take the Lie derivative of the volume form: that is, $L_X V = (div X) V$.  The volume form depends on an orientation, which can be locally chosen.  This way is actually probably easier for computing in local coordinates since you don't need to worry about a covariant derivative or Christoffel symbols.

For a reference, see e.g. Taylor's *Partial Differential Equations,* Vol. 1.  In Folland's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations,* there isn't much about Riemannian manifolds, but Folland does talk about how the Laplacian changes with respect to new coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

The Laplacian originates from physics. In particular, it arises as the linear differential operator in the Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional $f \mapsto E[f] = \int |\nabla f|^2$. You can derive formulas for the Laplacian on either Euclidean space or the unit sphere by differentiating this functional with respect to $f$ and determining the condition for a critical point.

You can figure out the relationship between the Euclidean and spherical Laplacians by observing that in polar co-ordinates, $|\nabla f|^2 = |\partial_rf|^2 + r^2|\partial_\theta f|^2$, where $\nabla$ is the Euclidean gradient and $\partial_\theta$ is the spherical gradient.

The recurrence relation for the spherical Laplacian arises from the observation in polar co-ordinates the $(n-1)$-dimensional spherical gradient can be written as $|\partial_\theta f|^2 = |\partial_\phi f|^2 + (\sin\phi)^2|\partial'_\theta f|^2$, where $\phi \in [0,\pi)$ is the co-ordinate giving the angle between a point and $e_n$, $\theta \in S^{n-2}$, and $\partial_\theta f$ is the $(n-2)$-dimensional spherical gradient.

These formulas, at least for dimensions 2 and 3, can be found in most textbooks on electromagnetic theory or mathematical physics. The trick is to use the same derivation given in these books but recast them in a more abstract arbitrary dimension form.

If you want to work things out using Riemannian geometry, I recommend using stereographic co-ordinates on the unit sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

I am very familiar with how these happen in $2$ and $3$ dimensions having worked through many problems in them.  

The generalization to $n$-dimensions here isn't looking very obvious. 

I was wondering if one can write down the all the christoffel symbols for the $S^n$ as a function of $n$ and then evaluate the laplacian? 

Let me look through the book by Rosenberg for details. 


Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ consider $f = f(r)$. Writing $\partial_j \equiv \partial/\partial x_j$ and $\partial_r \equiv \partial/\partial_r$, etc., we have that $\partial_j r = x_j/r$, so

$\partial_j f = (\partial_r f)(x_j r^{-1})$

and

$\partial_{jj} f = (\partial_{rr} f)(x_j^2 r^{-2}) + (\partial_r f)(r^{-1} - x_j^2 r^{-3})$.

Summing over $j$ and comparing with the Cartesian expression for $\Delta$ gives the decomposition into radial and spherical operators. To be explicit you should consider $f = f(r, \omega)$, where $\omega \in S^{n-1}$.

For a more general case, see the end of Chapter 2 of *The Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold: an introduction to analysis on manifolds* by Rosenberg. Unfortunately some of the relevant section (the Laplacian in exponential coordinates) is blocked both from Amazon and Google:

http://books.google.com/books?id=gzJ6Vn0y7XQC&dq=laplacian+on+a+riemannian+manifold&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: PS. The book is available on Rosenberg's website: http://math.bu.edu/people/sr/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Terras, *Harmonic analysis on symmetric spaces*.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

I have been looking at the book by Nolan Wallace and the papers by Camporesi for reference till now. 



Answer (score 0):

So I wrote up this small derivation drawing insights from the answer by Deane Yang and Steve Huntsman,

With respect to the Riemann-Christoffel connection on a riemannian manifold the laplacian on that manifold will have the form $$\nabla ^2 \phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \partial _{\mu} \left [  \sqrt{g} g^{\mu \nu} \partial _{\nu} \phi \right ]$$

where $g$ is the the determinant of the metric on the manifold and $\phi$ is some smooth scalar function on the manifold.

On can write the line element on $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as,

$d\Omega _n ^2 = d\theta _1 ^2 + sin^2 \theta_1 d\theta _2 ^2 + sin^2 \theta _1 sin^2 \theta_2 d\theta _3 ^3 +...+sin^2\theta _1 sin^2 \theta_2...sin^2 \theta_{n-2} sin^2 \theta_{n-1} d\theta _n ^2$

Then the line element on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ in polar coordinates can be written as,

$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega _n ^2$$

and 
$g_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} = r^{2n}g_{_{S^n}}$
where 
$g_{_{S^n}}  = (sin^2 \theta _1)^{n-1}(sin^2 \theta_2)^{n-2}...(sin^2 \theta _{n-2})^2(sin^2 \theta_{n-1})^1$

Therefore since the metric is diagonal $\nabla _{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} ^2 \phi = \frac{1}{r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} }} \partial _{\mu} \left [r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} } g^{\mu \mu}_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \partial _{\mu} \phi \right ]$

$=\frac{1}{r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} }} \partial _{r} \left [r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} } \partial _{r} \phi \right ] + \frac{1}{r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} }} \partial _{\theta _i} \left [r^n \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} } g^{\theta _i \theta _i}_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}} \partial _{\theta _i} \phi \right ]$

$=\frac{1}{r^n}\partial _r (r^n \partial_r \phi) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} }} \partial_{\theta _i} \left[ \sqrt{g_{_{S^n}} } 
\frac{g^{\theta _i \theta _i}_{S^n}} {r^2} \partial _{\theta _i} \phi \right]$

$=\frac{1}{r^n}\partial _r (r^n \partial_r \phi) + \frac{\nabla _{S^n}^2 \phi}{r^2}$

Therefore after doing the differentiation we have the final result,

$$\nabla _{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}^2 \phi = \frac{n}{r}\partial _r \phi + \partial _r ^2 \phi + \frac{\nabla _{S^n} ^2 \phi}{r^2}$$

And I don't see an neat way of writing the Laplacian on $S^n$ !

Comment: If you really want a single non-recursive formula for the Laplacian on $S^n$, then I recommend using the co-ordinates given by stereographic projection.

Otherwise, you can try to write down the recursive formula, giving the Laplacian on $S^n$ in terms of the Laplacian on $S^{n-1}$, using "polar co-ordinates" $(\rho, \theta) \in [0,\pi] \times S^{n-1} \rightarrow S^n \mapsto (\theta\sin\rho, \cos\rho) \in S^n$.